# Cannot allow mixed content in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools, mixed-content

I have pasted the following code in the console to try to import jQuery:

```js
var jq = document.createElement("script");
jq.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jq);
```

However this output is shown:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js".
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js ("script-src").
```

It would seem that I need to enable mixed content, as [the MDN article](http://mzl.la/1klqkmQ) says:

> 1. Click the padlock icon in the address bar.
> 2. Click the arrow in the Site Information panel.
> 3. Click <kbd>Disable protection for now</kbd>.

However there is no <kbd>Disable protection for now</kbd> button, as if it has never attempted to load the mixed content.

Is this a bug?  Why can't I enable mixed content in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, browsers stopped allowing content served through `http` from websites served through `https`.

So you can simply solve your issue by replacing "**http**://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" with "**https**://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js".

More details in the documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content